# How can I programatically change the (D8 core) workflow state of an entity with Content Moderation?

Tags: 8, configuration, workflows

I'm using Drupal 8.4-rc2.  When you enable the Workflow and Content Moderation modules, you automatically get the **Editorial Workflow** as a demonstration.

The states are as follows:

- Archived
- Draft
- Published

And the transitions are as follows:

- Create new draft (from draft/published to draft)
- Publish (from draft/published to published)

How can I programatically call a transition?  Or, how can I programatically change the state without calling a transition (although this seems to violate the spirit of having transitions defined in the first place)?

Specifically, I have a node subject to content moderation (states: archived, draft, published).  By default, on the edit node page, the node is saved in the original state (so a draft node is saved as a draft).  I want to add a second button "save as published" with a submit handler, but I don't understand how I can programatically change the state.

What I do understand so far is that workflows are entities and so are states, so it's different than Drupal 7 in which most workflow-type modules used fields to track what was going on.

I checked the [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module but there's nothing on configuration management/workflows yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A great example could be found in [Content Moderation module's code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/content_moderation/src/Form/EntityModerationForm.php#n126).

```php
$entity->set('moderation_state', $new_state);
if ($entity instanceof RevisionLogInterface) {
  $entity->setRevisionLogMessage($form_state->getValue('revision_log'));
  $entity->setRevisionUserId($this->currentUser()->id());
}
$entity->save();
```

Comment: $new_state, I think, is an ID number. How to find the ID for a state?

Comment: $new_state should be the machine name of the moderation state so a string

Answer (score 2):

I'm not heavily using D8 yet, but in D7's Workbench Moderation module nodes had a moderation_state field that was Draft or Published. Transitions in D7 were typically for User Role workflows whereas in code you typically modified the node states directly via node_load and node_save .... If D8 was inspired by the d7 module, the implementation may be similar.

Did you see the Tests referenced here found in the Examples links: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/workflows/overview and example node moderation field modifications here http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/content_moderation/tests/src/Functional/ModerationStateNodeTest.php