# Core Workflow: How to add Save as Draft button in form actions?

Tags: 8

On we create article we have 'Save' & 'Preview' button.

I would like to add 'Save as draft' button.

I found https://www.drupal.org/project/save_draft  But it's not for Drupal 8

Found this URL : https://sites.google.com/site/learnandmake/how-to-created-button-for-each-state-of-workflow-in-drupal-7

I tried with this

```
function custom_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['actions']['draft'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#class' => 'form-submit',
    '#name' => 'btn-draft',
    '#value' => t('Save as draft'),
    '#weight' => '-10',
    '#submit' => ['custom_module_node_form_submit']
  );
}
```

In the function

```
function custom_module_node_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $button_clicked = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'];

  if ($button_clicked == 'btn-draft') {
    if ($entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()) {
      $entity->set('moderation_state', 'draft');
      $entity->save();
    }
  }
}
```

Using workflow module.

So have state (Draft/Publish/Archive)

Once it save not able to alternative function for `node_form_submit($form, $form_state);` Currently it's giving error 'title` is missing in DB Query

Error

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {node_field_data} (nid,
>   vid, type, langcode, status, title, uid, created, changed, promote,
>   sticky, default_langcode, revision_translation_affected, weight,
>   publish_on, unpublish_on, publish_state, unpublish_state) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_14, :db_insert_placeholder_15,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_16, :db_insert_placeholder_17);

Comment: Drupal 8 has save as  unpublished button for a content. I think this might remove the requirement for Save Draft button.

Comment: @ShreyaShetty Sorry forgot to mention, Using workflow module. So need to save that state

Comment: @Julia Can you edit the question and mention if you are using the "Workflows" module coming from the core, or the [contributed workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) module?

Comment: Updates question @AjitS

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247359/custom-form-submit-handler-is-called-but-node-is-not-saved/ Got answer